# Apply changes button doesn't work when using SupportMapFragment

Tags: android

If I have `SupportMapFragment` then Apply changes button (yellow one) doesn't work with success (app would crash with `Error inflating class fragment` error)

I have to always press green button to see any changes

[image]

at 12 line I have

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Error:

```
Process: com.example.test, PID: 4940
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2485)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4189)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2233)
        at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4189) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

p.s. `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'` is used

Answer (score 0):

The one you call it yellow button is for instant run, the crash caused because the MapFragment will not be added the BackStack so when instant run the application it will not find an instance for it. You can Fix it by :

```
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("map");
        } else {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction mapTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mapTransaction.addToBackStack("map").add(R.id.map, mapFragment, "map").commit();
        }
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```